# constant lambda function in python

Tags: python, constants, lambda

How shall I define a constant lambda function in python?

I need it to evaluation expressions like

```
lam (array[1,2,3,4,5])
```

For now I used

```
lam = lambda t: 1 + t*0
```

It works but is it too wasteful?

Comment: What do you want the "constant lambda function" to do? Is the objective to return an array with all elements set to the same value? The code in the question does not work for me.

Comment: The source of confusion here:  Your `lam()` is not "working" for the reason you seem to think.  The whole array is being passed in `t` rather than the individual elements, and you are getting an array of 1's back just because of overloaded operator `+` between a scalar and an array, nothing to do with your constant lamda function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you just want to have a function that returns the same thing, no matter what arguments it's called with, That's A-OK!  You are not in any way obligated to *use* any of your arguments.

In python, `lambda` is a function without a name (and some other, unrelated limitations)

If you are going to take the lambda expression and immediately assign its return value to a variable, you are giving a function a name.  Don't do that, just define a regular function.  You should reach for lambda when you need to pass a function to another function, and the function you want to use is little, and doesn't even merit a name (like when it always returns `1`).  Python has a few such "high order functions" (functions that take other functions as arguments), `map`, `filter` and `reduce` are in the built in namespace.

```
#never!
always_return_one = lambda ignored_argument: 1

#OK: functions with names are def'ed not lambda'd
def always_return_one(ignored_argument):
    return 1

#Also OK: pass the lambda to another function as soon as you spell it.
modified_list = some_highorder_function(lambda ignored: 1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Some of the most used high order functions in python have a special syntax. In the case above, if the function was `map`, you can use a list comprehension like so:

```
modified_list = [1 for ignored in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

which reads a little easier and is consistently *faster*!

Answer (score 6):

It's conventional to use _ for unused arguments

```
lam = lambda _: 1
```

Answer (score 3):

how about just:

```
[1] * len(array)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the lambda function to ignore its parameter and always return `1`, simply don't use the parameter:

```
lam = lambda t: 1
```